# unable to initialise knob in an es6 module

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, es6-modules, jquery-knob

I'm trying to use `jquery knob` from within an ES6 module but having problems initializing within the module. At the moment I get an error of 'knob is not a function`

In my module I'm requiring the knob plugin like this:

```
let knob = require('knob'); //name from package.json
```

The code I'm working on is trying to get a progress bar for a fileupload (using the blueimp plugin)

Here's the basics of my code (it's a bit messy at the moment and will refactor once I get it working):

```
export const uploadHandler = class {

   constructor() {
        this.initControls();
        this.initFileupload();
        console.log('init fileupload', knob);
    }
    initFileupload = () =>{
        // Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
        $('#upload').fileupload({
            url: 'filemanager/upload',
            dataType: 'json',
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
            },
            done: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                    $('<p></p>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
                });
            },

            // This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
            //dropZone: $('#drop'),

            // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
            // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
            add: (e, data) => {
                $('#test').knob();

                let tpl = $('<li class="working row">' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-2">' +
                    '<input class="knob-control" type="hidden" value="0" data-width="48" data-height="48" data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" />' +
                    '<img src="/img/sample_content/upload-50x50.png">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-3 file-attribute">' +
                    '<p></p>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-2 file-attribute"></div>' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-2 file-attribute"><span></span></div>' +
                    '</li>');

                // Append the file name and file size
                tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name)
                    .append('<i> ' + formatFileSize(data.files[0].size) + '</i>');

                // Add the HTML to the UL element
                data.context = tpl.appendTo(this.ul);

                // Initialize the knob plugin
                tpl.find('input').knob();

                // Listen for clicks on the cancel icon
                tpl.find('span').click(function () {

                    if (tpl.hasClass('working')) {
                        jqXHR.abort();
                    }

                    tpl.fadeOut(function () {
                        tpl.remove();
                    });

                });
```

There's a bit more to the class that I've removed for brevity.

I'm unable to set the knob plugin on either my test element or the created `tpl` element.

In the output from the `console.log` in the constructor I get this output:

```
init fileupload ƒ (options){

  options = extend({
    value: 50,

    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,

    cursor: false,
    thickness: 0.35,
    lineCap: 'butt',
    readOnly: false,
    displayInput: true,

   …
```

Which appears to indicate the plugin is available.

But `tpl.find('input').knob();` or `$('#test').knob();` do not work - function not available.

How do I initiate the plugin - I assume it must be down to scope or the way the jquery object `tpl` is created but not sure how to resolve :(

Thank you

Comment: If you want to use es6 module syntax, you should use `import` syntax instead of `require` calls?

Comment: Hi, thank you - I did try that before and changed to `import 'knob';` but no change and remains `not a function`:(